# Comparing NIntegrate with definite integration

Tags: numerical-integration, distributions

I want to calculate without error a sum of double integrals with the following definitions for the functions within them:

```
fx[ x_ ] = PDF[NormalDistribution[10, 2], x];
Fx[ x_ ] = CDF[NormalDistribution[10, 2], x];
f[ x_ , y_ ] = Simplify[PDF[MultinormalDistribution[{10, 8},
        {{2^2, 0.5*2*1.5}, {0.5 2 1.5, 2.25}}], {x, y}]];
ϕm[q_ ] = Integrate[Integrate[(-q + x)*y*f[x, y],
          {x, q, 25}], {y, 2, 15}]/(1 - Fx[q]);
```

When I compute the differential in q of $ϕ[q]$ using two different methods, I get very different results. Compare:

```
D1[q_] = D[ϕm[q], q];
```

With:

```
Tdϕs = Table[{q,
          1/(1 - Fx[q]) NIntegrate[-y f[x , y ], {x, q, 25}, {y, 2, 15}] + 
    fx[q]/(1 - Fx[q])^2 NIntegrate[(x - q) y f[x, y], {x, q, 25}, {y, 2, 15}]},
          {q, 1, 23, 0.1}];
dϕs = Interpolation[Tdϕs, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

Look at the difference in results between these 2:

```
Table[{D1[q], dϕs[q]}, {q, 4, 16}]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  0.0599831 & -7.89327 \\
>  0.213901 & -7.6447 \\
>  0.584625 & -7.09157 \\
>  1.25085 & -6.1804 \\
>  2.17537 & -5.03748 \\
>  3.22484 & -3.88942 \\
>  4.26853 & -2.90709 \\
>  5.23671 & -2.14794 \\
>  6.11377 & -1.59297 \\
>  6.91058 & -1.19675 \\
>  7.64478 & -0.915004 \\
>  8.33155 & -0.71338 \\
>  8.97959 & -0.567722 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

If somebody can explain which is the best method (apart from the difference in computing time), I would be very grateful!

Comment: I think your second expression just isn't right. It cant be that simple, there should be a bunch of `D[Fx[q],q]` terms and such.

Comment: The expression of d\[Phi]s is in fact the differentiation of \[Phi]m in q when Mthematica has not yet replaced either f[x,y] nor Fx[q] by their respective definitions.